# Sync WordPress and Firebase password

Tags: php, wordpress, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to sync WordPress and Firebase password but it does not work:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;

$factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(__DIR__ . '/credentials.json');
$auth = $factory->createAuth();

add_action('password_reset', 'sync_password_to_firebase', 10, 2);

function sync_password_to_firebase($user, $new_pass) {
    global $auth;
    try {
        $firebaseUser = $auth->getUserByEmail($user->user_email);
        $auth->changeUserPassword($firebaseUser->uid, $new_pass);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        error_log('Failed to sync password to Firebase: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

WordPress seems to create a user but does not change the password even if I try do delete and recreate. My aim is to have the same password in bots systems.